# Replacement for DeviceInfo in phonegap > 1.5

Tags: ios, cordova

It seems that they have deprecated the Phonegap variable DeviceInfo as of Cordova 1.5 (I think I saw that it was technically deprecated for 1.5 as well, but left it in).  I know there is the device variable, but I was using the DeviceInfo variable to store some of my own data via the callback to

```
- (NSDictionary*)deviceProperties{...}
```

It seems that function is still called for the var device data, but it doesn't let me add any data to that variable.  Does anyone know if there is anyway to get back the functionality of having custom device data or is it gone forever?

Comment: OK so I found a solution for this to simply write in the variable in a category implementation of CDVViewController method viewDidAppear.  Hoping someone out there can post a better answer today or tomorrow, but if not I will post the full explanation as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so the workaround I came up with was to simply create the variable myself in a javascript call so that the rest of the javascript code still access it as needed.  I etd a catagory to override

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;
```

and in the implementation I called the following code

```
NSString* jsString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"window.DeviceInfo = {param1:%@, param2:%@}}", param1, param2];
[self.viewController.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
```

That added code allowed for backward compatibility with code based on the editable DeviceInfo variable that has been removed.